# Is there a way to make a django template variable variable into a for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this in my model:

```
tank0 = models.ForeignKey(nb200V1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pmp300Tank0')
tank0MQTT = models.BooleanField(default = False)
tank1 = models.ForeignKey(nb200V1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pmp300Tank1')
tank1MQTT = models.BooleanField(default = False)
tank2 = models.ForeignKey(nb200V1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pmp300Tank2')
tank2MQTT = models.BooleanField(default = False)
tank3 = models.ForeignKey(nb200V1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pmp300Tank3')
tank3MQTT = models.BooleanField(default = False)
tank4 = models.ForeignKey(nb200V1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pmp300Tank4')
tank4MQTT = models.BooleanField(default = False)
tank5 = models.ForeignKey(nb200V1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pmp300Tank5')
tank5MQTT = models.BooleanField(default = False)
tank6 = models.ForeignKey(nb200V1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='pmp300Tank6')
tank6MQTT = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

I would like in my template to make a for loop to generate the html and set the variable with the i in the for loop like this:

```
{% for i in "0123456" %}
<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Tank # {{forloop.counter}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                        <label><b>Serial:</b></label>
                        <a href="#" id="{{obj.serial}}_tank{{i}}">{{obj.tank{{i}}.serial}}</a>
                        <small id="{{obj.tank{{i}}.serial}}_serial_ts" class="form-text text-muted">{{obj.tank{{i}}.timeStamp}}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

{% endfor %}

Is there anyway way to do this ?

Comment: I think the problem is the modeling. This looks like a one-to-many relation. So instaead of using some `tank...` `ForeignKey`s, you probably should let the `nb200V1` refer to the model, such that zero, one, or more `nb200V1`s can refer to that model.

Answer (score 0):

I agree w/ @Willem that you should use a reverse foreign key.

But if you *do* keep that model structure then what about adding a model property that returns a list of fields:

```py
@property
def tank_list(self):
   return [
     (getattr(self, f"tank{i}"), getattr(self, f"tank{i}MQTT")
     for i in range(7)
   ]
```

Then in the template you could just loop through that list.  To get the 0th, 1st element from each tuple just do something like:

```
{% for tank_fields in obj.tank_list %}
  {{ tank_fields.0 }}
  {{ tank_fields.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```